# Adding an additional email address to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I sent out invites to a specific calendar. One of the recipients signed in to the calendar via a Hotmail account which is where he redirects some of his mail. He can't access the calendar. I have added his alternate Hotmail address to the calendar group, but I can't see how to resend the calendar link to him.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resend the calendar invite you need to remove him from the guest list, then add him again.